# /usr/bin/node: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to install npm live-server on wsl (windows subsystem for linux)

after i install nodejs and npm with:

`sudo apt install nodejs npm`

and try to install live-server with npm:

`npm install live-server`

I get this error:

`/usr/bin/node: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

and not only when installing live-server.. it return this error on any npm command for example:

`npm -v`

how can i fix it?

Comment: There's not enough information here to reproduce this issue.  In particular, the behaviour of `npm install` depends greatly on the contents of the current working directory.  Also, it's unclear which distro you are using.  FWIW, I can run this in an Ubuntu container in Docker in wsl-2 in an empty directory and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have to use Kali? I tried it under VirtualBox and it seemed very prone to bugs/crashes. I'd go for Debian or Ubuntu if you can (at least if you are not yet an expert) as they will more likely work 'out of the box'

Comment: I just did a fresh install of Kali and it was absolutely fine with the commands you have above, node 18 was installed and I could then use npm to install live-server

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you use ubuntu:**

The version of Node.js included with Ubuntu, version 10.19, is unsupported. You should not use this version in production.

Here is a good tutorial of how to install nodejs from DigitalOcean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04

1. `cd ~`
2. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh`
3. `sudo bash /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh`
4. `sudo apt install nodejs`

Comment: George, can you just check that? As far as I can see, the current Ubuntu includes nodejs 18 (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/nodejs)

Comment: removed old nodejs and npm, and installed them exactly as you provided.
and got this:


`Could not determine Node.js install directory`

Comment: and btw I use linux.. not ubuntu. maybe thats the problem? I dont really know

Comment: @MohamedAshraf What Linux distribution do you use?

Comment: @georgeCkito kali in wsl

Comment: @PeterHull Oh, I assumed he was using Ubuntu LTS 20.04. As that version uses v10

Comment: @MohamedAshraf In that case you might wanna try installing nodejs using nvm. Try [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl)

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem solved in this way

```bash
nvm install node
nvm use node
```