# having a syntax error any time i use an npm/nodejs command

Tags: node.js, npm, debian

any time i invoke npm in debian (literally any command, could be legit or not), it gives me the

```
/usr/bin/node: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

error. npm version is 9.2.0. same thing with nodejs:

```
/usr/bin/nodejs: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

nodejs version is 18.19.0

tried removing and reinstalling them again. even reinstalled my debian wsl, same problem, still. i used the command

```
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

Answer (score -1):

I have searched in google with your error message and got it .
***[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767564/usr-bin-node-1-syntax-error-unexpected)***
You will get the answer.

But if you don't find the answer. Follow below

[go to this link to install nvm (node version manager)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#installing-and-updating)

after installing `nvm`

To see if `nvm` is installed . Run this command in your terminal

```
 nvm -v
```

Then install node using this command

`nvm install node`

You will find how to use `nvm` to install and remove of specific `node` version [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#usage)